# Cannot get Access Token from Godaddy Poynt

Tags: php, access-token, godaddy-api

I am trying to get access token from GoDaddy Poynt using the following PHP code:

I use Firebase JWT class for PHP to encode JWT and CURL to post the request.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

require_once('../common/common_include.php');
require_once('../plugin/php-jwt/vendor/autoload.php');

// *********************************************************************
// *********************** First create the JWT ************************

$secret_key  = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
********
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

$date   = new DateTimeImmutable();
$expire_at     = $date -> modify('+6 minutes') -> getTimestamp();      // Add 60 seconds

$domain_name = "*****.com";
$username = "*****@gmail.com";               
$app_id = "urn:aid:****" ;
$username = "****";               
$password = "****" ;

$request_data = [
    "exp" => $expire_at ,                  
    "iat" => $date -> getTimestamp() ,        
    "iss" => $app_id ,                 
    "sub" => $app_id ,        
    "aud" => "https://services.poynt.net",
    "jti" => bin2hex(random_bytes(32))                 
];
  
  
// Encode the array to a JWT string.
$jwt = JWT::encode(
    $request_data,      //Data to be encoded in the JWT
    $secret_key, // The signing key
    'HS512'     // Algorithm used to sign the token, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40#section-3
);

// ****************************** End of JWT ***************************
// *********************************************************************
  
// Initialize and use curl to connect
$curl_obj = curl_init();

// Get curl to POST
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_URL,"https://services.poynt.net/token");

// Build the curl request to be posted 
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_HEADER,"Accept: application/json");
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_HEADER,"api-version: 1.2");
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_HEADER,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
            ,"grantType=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=" . $jwt) ;

curl_setopt($curl_obj,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); // Return result back
$response = curl_exec($curl_obj) ;
curl_close($curl_obj);

// ******************** End of Sending to Payment Gateway *********************
// ****************************************************************************
```

At the end I get the error message that the JWT is not valid

At the end I get the error message that the JWT is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the solution. I should have used RS256 and not HS512 for encoding

```
// Encode the array to a JWT string.
$jwt = JWT::encode(
    $request_data,      //Data to be encoded in the JWT
    $secret_key, // The signing key
    'RS256'     // Algorithm used to sign the token, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40#section-3
);
```